# SP2013 search result type icon not showing up at client side

Tags: search-results

I am testing the search result page on the WFE server and client PC.
By search the same keyword, I can get exactly the same result on WFE or client PC. However, none of icon display at client PC regardless which user I login to test.

On the WFE I checked the icon source is like `https://domainname/_layouts/15/images/icpdf.png`. On client PC, I cannot find anything in the source. Also on client PC user can browse `https://domainname/_layouts/15/images/icpdf.png` without problem.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problems.

I would bet on clearing out the cache on the load balancer (if applicable) and/or at the client browser.

Also, make sure all your customization resources and checked in, published and approved.